# Getting the Nth non-null column in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with a collection of nullable columns. What I need to do is 'shift' these columns "left" so that column 1 contains the first non-null value,  column 2 contains the second non-null value, etc.

e.g.

```
This:

<null>, <null>, foo,    bar,    baz,    buz
<null>, <null>, <null>, <null>, foo,    bar
<null>, <null>, <null>, foo,    bar,    baz
```

needs to become this:

```
foo,    bar,    baz,    buz,    <null>, <null>
foo,    bar,    <null>, <null>, <null>, <null>
foo,    bar,    baz,    <null>, <null>, <null>
```

I can be certain that the data contains 0 or more  columns followed by 1 or more non-null columns.

I can imagine a way to acheive this with gratuitous use CASE statements, but I'd rather not create such an abomination.

Anyone have a clue how to get this done easily?

Comment: It's important to know: do you know every column name, and are the number of columns fixed? You only need to create an abomination because this kind of data model is not ideal (though I understand it is sometimes necessary). You might be able to make something less abominable with `NVL` instead. Can we assume the data in the columns is unique, i.e. no foo,bar,foo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way is an unpivot/pivot.  You can do this as:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then col end) as col1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then col end) as col2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then col end) as col3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then col end) as col4,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then col end) as col5,
       max(case when seqnum = 6 then col end) as col6
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by pos) as seqnum
      from ((select id, col1 as col, 1 as pos from t) union all
            (select id, col2 as col, 2 as pos from t) union all
            (select id, col3 as col, 3 as pos from t) union all
            (select id, col4 as col, 4 as pos from t) union all
            (select id, col5 as col, 5 as pos from t) union all
            (select id, col6 as col, 6 as pos from t) 
           ) t
      where col is not null
     ) t
group by id;
```

Because Redshift is a columnar database, the `union all` should be about as efficient as any other way of unpivoting the data.